# overflow auto doesn't work in child element when parent has fixed size

Tags: html, css, overflow

I created a parent div with fixed size which contains 2 children, but I want that only the second one will have `overflow: auto;`

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected...

Here is my snippet:

```css
.parent
{
 height: 200px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: #F00;
 padding: 10px;
}

.second-child
{
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="first-child">
  Some content
 </div>
 <hr />
 <div class="second-child">
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
 </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you haven't given any dimensions to the child so it cannot overflow - give it a max-height of 100% and it should work

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `max-height` CSS a property. With the help of  `max-height`, You can set the maximum height. If the content is exceeding the maximum height, Y scroll will be automatically implemented.

**Code**

```css
.parent
{
 height: 200px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: #F00;
 padding: 10px;
}

.second-child
{
 overflow: auto;
        max-height:100px
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="first-child">
  Some content
 </div>
 <hr />
 <div class="second-child">
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please offer some explanation rather than just posting code.

Comment: @AndyG sorry to answer the question without explanation. The answer has been edited.

Comment: But I need the second child to fill the remaining space that the first one left in the parent, while idk its height. Setting the second child to a fixed size won't work as I want.

Comment: @StyleSh1t meanwhile you can read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44156191/6821441

Comment: @StyleSh1t https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/how-do-i-dynamically-set-the-height-of-a-div-to-another-div/ check this out

Answer (score 0):

<s>Updated:</s>

Define a `max-height` to tell the browser after what length the overflow would take place

### Update 2:

1. Make the container a table
2. Make the other 2 div's table-rows
3. In 2nd div, put the text in a position relative following position absolute

```css
.parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #F00;
  padding: 10px;
  display: table;
}

.first-child,
.second-child {
  display: table-row;
}

.second-child {
  height: 100%;
}

.second-child-content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.second-child-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-child">
    Some content
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="second-child">
    <div class="second-child-content-wrapper">
      <div class="second-child-content">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You put a fixed height in the calc (25px). How can I avoid it when idk the first child's height?

Comment: Updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should set a max-value before the overflow kicks in...

**EDIT:** Set max-height to % so that it will always be within you changing needs. I kept it as 80% here since it fits in within the second-child nicely

```
.second-child
{
  max-height: 80%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Now it should be good!

```css
.parent
{
 height: 200px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: #F00;
 padding: 10px;
}

.second-child
{
  max-height: 80%;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="first-child">
  Some content
 </div>
 <hr />
 <div class="second-child">
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Refer to my comment to @Abhishek Ekaanth

Comment: Changed as per your requirement hopefully... :D

Comment: @NikhilEshvar he just said that he doesn't know the height of EITHER of the divs

Comment: And that's why I set it in percentage so that it accomadates based on the size of content