# How to calculate distance of element in CSS only?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a sticky header and above that sticky header, I have one div which has dynamic content.

I am not sure how much should I give to top:???? as top div height is not fixed.

is there any way to calculate sticky div position from the top or is there any way to count top:?? from the previous element

I am looking for pure CSS solution

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.content {
  background-color: gray;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.footer {
  top: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"> runtime example text </div>
  <div class="header"> header text </div>
  <div class="footer"> footer text </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but top div is not sticky, and it has dynamic height hence i am not able to calculate top position for sticky div

Comment: It might help answers if you were to provide an example of the HTML and CSS you've got so far. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the height of an element using css only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153866/how-can-i-get-the-height-of-an-element-using-css-only)

Comment: Why exactly don't you insert whatever is above the header into the header?

Comment: I can't cover myself as to what you actually want. I came to know that you want to calculate the height of the `.content` div and the if the height is more then you want the sticky div to shift that much from the top?

Comment: top:10px for you sticky element means it will stop scrolling at 10px, not set me at 10 px from top. add some lines to content and see what happens. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/voOwvL