# Get what x% of an element is

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set the margins of an **HTML** element to be **x%** of its size. Tried using `margin-bottom: 50%` or `margin-bottom: 50vm` but it gets **x%** of the screen size.

Code:

```css
#task_box {
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="task_box">
<input type="text" id="task_box">
<input type="text" id="task_box">
```

I want to set this to the **task_box** object.

Comment: `id`'s should be unique!

Comment: As per [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin), a margin specified as a percentage is relative to the **width** of the containing block.

Comment: I think, you have to use js

Comment: @RichardDeeming It's actually "The size of the margin as a percentage, relative to the width of the _containing block_."

Comment: Can you show me the answer with code?

Comment: the default size of height of an input is 15px. Can he add "margin-bottom: calc( 15 / 2 );"?

Comment: @saleh I would just use js cz you can‘t say that an input has always a height of 15px, it‘s browser dependent and not really responive

Comment: yes, you're right, but then he can add media query for each device

Comment: I just want to know how to get 50% from the task_box height and set its margins to it

Comment: Don't you give the height value to the task_box?

Comment: I want to get that value and set its margins to it

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153866/how-can-i-get-the-height-of-an-element-using-css-only/44156191) question help with you

Comment: Doesn't. Also, when I output the heigh of the textbox it's always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is using JS.

```js
const taskBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".task_box");


taskBoxes.forEach(taskBox => {
  var height = taskBox.offsetHeight;
  var marginBottom = height / 2;
  taskBox.style.marginBottom = marginBottom + 'px';
});
```

```css
.task_box {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="task_box">
<input type="text" class="task_box">
<input type="text" class="task_box">
```

Answer (score 0):

it helps to solve the problem

```css
.task_box {
  margin-bottom: calc(100% - 50%);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="task_box">
<input type="text" class="task_box">
<input type="text" class="task_box">
```

Comment: It gets 100% - 50% of the screen. I want it to get the size from the task_box

Comment: okey, you should use javascript.